# How to set today date dynamically

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

Hi I have a dropdown named "Calendar type". I have four values like "Today,Operating,Leave,Events". I want to display today date automatically when I select the value "Today" in dropdown. I dont know how to achieve this. please advise me if you have ideas.

**this is my form.html**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-5">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Calender Type</span>
                <% if @calendarlists != nil then%>
                    <%= collection_select(:calendar,:calendar_type, @calendarlists, :parameter, :value,{:prompt=> "Select Calendar Type"},{:class=>"form-control"}) %>
                <%else%>
                    <select id="calendar_calendar_type" name="calendar[calendar_type]" class="form-control">
                        <option value="">Select Calendar Type</option>
                    </select>
                <%end%>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**for start date**

```
<%= f.text_field :start_date, :id => 'fromdate',:placeholder => "Start Date", :class => "form-control",:autocomplete => :off,:value => @calendar.start_date.try(:strftime,"%d/%m/%Y"), :readonly => true %>
```

**for end date**

```
<%= f.text_field :expiration_date, :id => 'todate',:placeholder => "End Date", :class => "form-control",:autocomplete => :off,:value => @calendar.expiration_date.try(:strftime,"%d/%m/%Y"), :readonly => true %>
```

**this is datepicker for another leave,events,operating**

```
<script>
    $("#fromdate").datepicker({
        minDate : new Date(),
        dateFormat : 'dd/mm/yy',
        changeMonth : true,
        changeYear : true,
        numberOfMonths : 1,
        onClose : function(selectedDate) {
            $("#todate").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
            this.focus();
        }
    });
    $("#todate").datepicker({
        minDate : new Date(),
        dateFormat : 'dd/mm/yy',
        changeMonth : true,
        changeYear : true,
        numberOfMonths : 1,
        onClose : function(selectedDate) {
            $("#fromdate").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
            this.focus();
        }
    }); 
</script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
 var currentDate = new Date();  
$("#fromdate").datepicker("setDate",currentDate);
$("#todate").datepicker("setDate",currentDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solved issue:**

Add a javascript onchange method

```
<% if @calendarlists != nil then%>
        <%= collection_select(:calendar,:calendar_type, @calendarlists, :parameter, :value,{:prompt=> "Select Calendar Type"},{:onchange=>'changeDate(this)',:class=>"form-control"}) %>
<%else%>
        <select id="calendar_calendar_type" name="calendar[calendar_type]" class="form-control">
            <option value="">Select Calendar Type</option>
        </select>
<%end%>
```

**JS function**

```
function changeDate(obj) {
        if(obj.value == "TOD"){
            today = new Date();
            todayFormat = today.getDate() + "/" + (today.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + today.getFullYear().toString();
            document.getElementById("fromdate").value = todayFormat;
            document.getElementById("todate").value = todayFormat;                              
        }
}
```